# Apache - restrict simultaneous connections per directory?

Tags: apache-httpd

Is it possible to restrict the number of possible simultaneous connections to a certain directory on my server?
I have a public directory which I want to share many download-able files, yet its popularity is straining my server to the max - causing it to crash, so I want to restrict the connections to that certain directory.

When I use "Deny from all" directive - then my server doesn't get swamped.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons but if it's that popular why don't you look into getting the server more resources instead of limiting the connections?

Comment: Too costly mate, can't afford it...

Comment: If all else fails, run a `thttpd` (or anything really) locally with fewer threads/workers/simultaneous connections and `ProxyPass` to that? When the local server gets full, your apache will run into proxy timeouts. (Also, have you looked at `mod_bw`?)

Comment: Why don't you just host the content elsewhere and link to it, like Dropbox or Google Drive?

Comment: I'm considering that, though I rather not to..

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with virtual hosts using MaxClientsVHost.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80> or use a NameVirtualHost

MaxClientsVHost 100

ServerName public-files-subdomain.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pub-share
```

If have access to DNS records for mydomain.com, can add a CNAME for this public-files-subdomain.mydomain.com. Then use NameVirtualHost in Apache for that new subdomain in order to allow MaxClientsVHost and other useful customization. Separate IP address, expense not required with that particular approach.

Comment: This is correct, however as I understand it requires assigning different port / IP / host-name that will point to that location (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) - which is not the kind of solution I'm looking for...